# Sklearn: Is there any way to debug Pipelines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have created some pipelines for classification task and I want to check out what information is being present/stored at each stage (e.g. text_stats, ngram_tfidf). How could I do this.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features',FeatureUnion([
                ('text_stats', Pipeline([
                            ('length',TextStats()),
                            ('vect', DictVectorizer())
                        ])),
                ('ngram_tfidf',Pipeline([
                            ('count_vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize_bigram_stem,stop_words=stopwords)),
                            ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer())
                        ]))
            ])),   
    ('classifier',MultinomialNB(alpha=0.1))
])
```

Answer (score 21):

I find it at times useful to temporarily add a debugging step that prints out the information you are interested in. Building on top of the example from the sklearn example [1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html), you could do this to for example to print out the first 5 lines, shape, or whatever you need to look at before the classifier is called:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import samples_generator
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator

class Debug(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def transform(self, X):
        print(pd.DataFrame(X).head())
        print(X.shape)
        return X

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

X, y = samples_generator.make_classification(n_informative=5, n_redundant=0, random_state=42)
anova_filter = SelectKBest(f_regression, k=5)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
anova_svm = Pipeline([('anova', anova_filter), ('dbg', Debug()), ('svc', clf)])
anova_svm.set_params(anova__k=10, svc__C=.1).fit(X, y)

prediction = anova_svm.predict(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse your [Pipeline()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) tree using `steps` and `named_steps` attributes. The former is a list of tuples `('step_name', Step())` while the latter gives you a dictionary constructed from this list

[FeatureUnion()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) content could be explored the same way using `transformer_list` attribute