# Scikit-learn Pipeline - Execution order of transformers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am working on a text classifier for which I want to do the following

1. Create new features on the text (like number of words, number of hash tags, etc) with a customer transformer **TextCounts**
2. Clean the text with a custom transformer **CleanText** and apply **CountVectorizer** on it
3. Combine the features of step 1 and 2 as input for my classifier

I managed to create a Pipeline for this, but I am not sure whether it runs like explained above.

```
features = FeatureUnion(n_jobs=-1,
    [('textcounts', TextCounts())
    , Pipeline([
        ('cleantext', CleanText())
        , ('vect', vect)
        ])
    ])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', features)
    , ('clf', clf)
])
```

In fact, I am not sure whether the CountVectorizer is being applied on the cleaned text or the original text. Is there a way to figure that out? Thanks!

Comment: FeatureUnion will supply the same input data to all its internal transformers. So what you are trying to do here is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps within the FeatureUnion will be applied in parallel (as you allow as many jobs as you have cores with n_jobs=-1, even actually in parallel). So yes, the CountVectorizer will be applied to the cleaned text.

I think the graphics in [this](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html) blog post make it quite clear.

Regarding "Is there a ways to find out?", see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802465/sklearn-is-there-any-way-to-debug-pipelines/46591092#46591092) for further questions.